# Laravel - Toggle value in database with checkbox and ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, checkbox

I want to toggle a boolean value in my table with a checkbox through jquery and ajax.

So whenever a user ticks the the checkbox it should toggle the value in table.

So far i came up with this but i need help:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("input:checkbox").change(function() { 
            var isChecked = $("input:checkbox").is(":checked") ? 1:0; 
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'/activation',
                headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': '{{ csrf_token() }}' },
                data: $('.checkbox').serialize(),
                    success:function(data){

                    }
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: What exactly is not working? So far you've only shown how you do an ajax...

Comment: true...it's not working at all, i don't know what to put in my controller method si if that checkbox was 0 it should change the value in DB table and vice versa

Comment: Welp, if it's a 0(or a 1 for that matter) then `Table::where('someField', 'someValue')->update(['someField' => 'someValue'])`. Have a look at [their docs](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent#updates), if you have specific questions, me and probably everybody else here, would be more than happy to help.

Comment: OK i'll try to write the question better

Comment: @Andrew i did it....maybe you could tell me if i can make it better

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only thing I'd modify would be returning an answer to the ajax call to let it know what's happening.

```
public function activation(Request $request)
{

    $user = User::findOrFail($request->user_id);

    if($user->active == 1){
        $user->active = 0;
    } else {
        $user->active = 1;
    }

    return response()->json([
      'data' => [
        'success' => $user->save(),
      ]
    ]);
}
```

---

```
And now in the front-end part:

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("input:checkbox").change(function() {
    var user_id = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id');

    $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'/activation',
            headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': '{{ csrf_token() }}' },
            data: { "user_id" : user_id },
            success: function(data){
              if(data.data.success){
                //do something
              }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

---

[jQuery Ajax documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: I have a prepared success flash message so how can i use that....i have putted it in my answer

Comment: I'm sorry, see what exactly?

Comment: this part is what i need in your answer if(data.success){
                //do something
              }

Comment: No, definitely not. That's the point of ajax, no reload. Do a `console.log(data)` to see what's in there. Learn to debug, it's a very good skill to have.

Comment: yes i understand now....but how to make some feedback for user...what to put here:  if(data.success){ //do something }

Comment: That's up to you. You can trigger a success message by adding a div, show an alert, add a green border to the message, I dunno mate, your call.

Comment: I need an example

Comment: You need to learn how to google mate. [jQuery append](http://api.jquery.com/append/) for example.

Answer (score 9):

[@andre](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40218587/5046652)'s answer is correct but

```
    if($user->active == 1){
        $user->active = 0;
    } else {
        $user->active = 1;
    }
```

this part can be done by a **single line**

```
$user->active = !$user->active;
```

Answer (score -1):

in model create a method

```
function toggleActive ()
{

  $this->active!=(int)$this->active;
  return $this;
}
```

in controller

```
$model->toggleActive()->save();
```